# Google Drive API get only one property

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API V3 to get custom properties from alot of files. 
I only need one property out of the properties collection. Is it possible to set the fields attribute so i can only get the one property?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fields is part of the [Standard Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters) valid for all of the Google discovery apis.

> fields
>     Selector specifying a subset of fields to include in the
>   response.  For more information, see the partial response section in
>   the Performance Tips document. Use for better performance.

Yes you can specify fields.

Comment: It would help to demonstrate what specific `fields` value would allow specifying the one property (say `my-property` to be returned). I tried fields=`files/id,files/properties/my-property` and it only returned the ID.